# I am confused between selection of limits for joint distribution

Tags: probability, joint-distribution

I am given the following joint distribution of two random variables X and Y:

$$            f(x,y)=2y   \\   0<y<1, 0<x<y         $$

Now I need to find the marginal PDF of X but how do I select the limits? I am really confused. What is the general method for selection of limits?

Comment: Hi, welcome. Please add the `self-study` tag and read its [wiki](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info). Here are some hints: 1) Draw $0 < y < 1$ in the $xy$-plane. 2) Draw $x = y$. 3) Where is the $x$-coordinate smaller than $y$-coordinate?

Comment: You don't have to select any limits: they are given to you.  We have many questions just like yours, so consider searching our site.  Try https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=marginal+pdf+self-study+answers%3A1.  Regardless, @Jim's advice to **draw a picture** is always good to follow.